# recursive directory iterator results: filter out specific characters from resultant paths

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, directory

I'm trying to return all unique instances paths from a specified directory, recursively.

I'm using `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`.  I also would like to omit any instances of paths that contain '.' in them, which is where I'm having trouble.

Here's what I've got going as a test:

```
<?php

function test($dir){

    $dirArray = []; // the array to store dirs
    $path = realpath($dir);

    $dirs = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dirs, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    // loop through all objects and store names in dirArray[]
    foreach($objects as $name => $object){
        if($object->isDir() && strpos($object->getBasename(), '.') !== true) {
          $dirArray[] = $name;
          echo "test: " . $object->getBasename() . "\n";
        }
    }

    print_r($dirArray);
}

test('/some/dir');

?>
```

This code *nearly* does what I need.  It returns all unique dirs, but includes those with a '.' in the path name.

Comment: do you have a sample directory name that has that problem? maybe like `path/to/directory.io/yeah`. so this one shouldn't be included?

Comment: it's all git stuff, so `/blah/.git/blah/blah`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another checker inside, and try to use `->getPathname()` instead:

```
if($object->isDir() && strpos($object->getPathname(), '.') === false) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

This just basically means, if this is a directory AND if pathname does not contain that `.`

Comment: @jml nope, it will never be compared to true. its either `0-n` or `false`. positions `0 - to whatever number` if it exists. `false` if not found